# How can I request a rollback for an improper edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rollbacks

I noticed an edit (that somehow was accepted without rejects). That I believe should not have been an approved edit, but I don't have the ability to rollback this myself due to my low reputation. How do I go about requesting a rollback on an edit? Should I flag the question with details? I don't think a re-edit would be a good idea in this case.

[Here is the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26368682/revisions)

Comment: Another suggested edit would be fine (remember to explain *why* you think it should be rolled back and fix any other issues it may have) or post in a chatroom where others may have the necessary rep. I don't think flagging is necessary or appropriate at this point.

Comment: @codeMagic I was thinking of flagging for moderator attention with details stating that it should be rolled-back. But yeah, I agree with you that a flag is not necessary. I'll try a suggested edit.

Comment: Taken care of now. If you look at the reviewer's stats you'd see why it was approved. Not many rejections at all in that crowd... *sigh*

Comment: Flagged the fudge out of that.  Hopefully our faithful roboreviewers will get a nice long vacation for their service.

Comment: @Will I would add that, if flagging, be sure to point out that it is *because roboreviewers* and not just because the edit should be rolled back

Comment: @codeMagic Oh, yes, was very specific about persons and punishments.

Comment: @Will good! :D But I misunderstood your last comment. I thought you were telling Spencer to flag it. I got you now

Answer (score 2):

[This comment by user codeMagic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274474/how-can-i-request-a-rollback-for-an-improper-edit#comment105900_274474) provides an answer:

> Another suggested edit would be fine (remember to explain why you
>   think it should be rolled back and fix any other issues it may have)
>   or post in a chatroom where others may have the necessary rep. I don't
>   think flagging is necessary or appropriate at this point.

Try the chat room first since it avoids the overhead of the suggested edit queue.