# How to proceed when a user removes his questions' content and you don't have enough privileges to roll it back?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

I'm talking especifically about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742852/allow-locale-switching-rails-i18n-http-accept-language) question, but this is not the first time I see something like this.

Comment: That is vandalism, flag a moderator.

Comment: Jeopardy Answer: [What is a ragequit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171581/what-does-it-mean-to-ragequit)

Comment: The user ultimately owns their question. If they get trolled, they get pissed, and remove their question to shake the trolls off their back. That is a sign that something is getting really wrong with this site. But who would listen?

Comment: @aleh I think that is less of a problem on this site lately.

Comment: @ajeh I don't know. Quoting [BradleyDotNet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742852/allow-locale-switching-rails-i18n-http-accept-language#comment45085023_27742852): "Content on Stack Overflow is intended to help everyone, not just you [the OP]."

Comment: I had something similar. A question was edited to almost empty, I rolled it back, within a day the question's text was replaced by words like "I wanted to delete the question". So rather than start an edit war I raised a custom flag. A moderator rolled it back again and, since then, the question has not been modified.

Comment: @ajeh: They gave SO a non-revocable, transferable licence to publish their content, and **they don't have the right to throw away other peoples effort** anyway. Vandalizing, even if it was their own contribution, is not permitted.

Comment: Related: [How can I request a rollback for an improper edit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274474/2359271)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First off, in a high traffic tag, I wouldn't worry about it *too* much, at least initially. Users crawling the "active" page will see it and fix it most of the time.

Failing that, or if you feel industrious, you should just paste in the old markup as a suggested edit. Use "rollback to revision X" as the comment, though it should be pretty easily approved.

If the user is doing this to multiple posts, raise a custom moderator flag. They can do the rollbacks, and potentially suspend the user to "cool down".

Comment: There's no need to go to chat or flag a mod, just suggest the edit.

Comment: @Servy Does doing a rollback do anything besides a standard edit/suggestion, or is it just a shortcut? And flagging a mod *is* important if they are doing this to all their posts.

Comment: There is no "rollback" button if you don't have edit privs; you'd need to simply copy the markup of the last good revision, start an edit, and paste that markup in as the new text.  It's a few extra clicks, but it's not that bad.

Comment: The system will flag 1) when it detects a rollback war 2) when a user hits the daily rate limit for edits/deletes, but it's totally fine to raise a custom flag on a rogue user just in case.

Comment: Interestingly, *this* user defaced 7 or 8 their posts (not sure why they stopped, perhaps the edit limit kicked in?). They have subsequently been suspended.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: An actual rollback will [automatically clear any flags on the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/148988).

Comment: @josh3736: I think custom moderator flags still apply, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @josh3736 all that [faq] says is it will clean offensive flags, nothing else

Comment: I thought that given enough rep you can delete your own question. How is that different from what this guy did?

Comment: @zespri: Question deletion is allowed only if it has no upvoted answers.  Not related to rep.

Comment: @BenVoigt, ah that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I just gave it a try and you are right. Even though that the 'delete' link is there, after you confirm the deletion it would say that deleting upvoted answers are not allowed.

Answer (score -5):

I would most likely guess that it has more to the question being a 'homework' question to which then a user decides it was too risky to post.

Comment: Thats quite possible, but it doesn't justify the user's actions

Comment: These are considerations that should have been thought of *before* posting the question.  After you post it, if it is a not awful question it will likely stick around.  Defacing it only brings more attention to it.

Answer (score -14):

Well, if your question goes unanswered or is considered "not good enough to be on this site" -which happens quite often, then the posters like me think its probably not worth putting it up here and we go on and remove/delete it in good faith (that the site shouldn't be riddled with useless stuff that the contributors aren't interested in handling. Whats wrong with that ?

Comment: If so, then *delete it* (via the delete link). Vandalizing your content helps no one

Comment: yes, sure - but if you delete it shows a warning sign saying deleting will ban you or something to that effect

Comment: And vandalizing it will net you a bunch of downvotes, which will ban you even *faster*. It can also net you a suspension. Not a good strategy if avoiding a Q-ban is your goal.

Comment: I couldnt care less my friend. If the site owners are okay with the site littered with useless stuff all over - by all means, be my guest

Comment: The theory is that if the question can't be deleted (due to upvoted answers), the content is valuable enough to keep around. Vandalizing the question at this point does *nothing* to help the site quality. Of course, users are free to *actually* delete their posts if they have no upvoted answers.

Comment: Content that is considered "not good enough" will be deleted by trusted users.  A user can delete their question if there are no upvoted answers, and if they can't delete it, they can contact users with that power via flag or chatroom.  Working around the limitation that questions with answers can't be deleted by changing the question content to garbage is a terrible idea.